# Microsoft Edge is returning different values than Chrome when document.getSelection() is called

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to use the `getSelection` function from document DOM to retrieve the element/component selected on Edge but I'm not getting any values on the anchorNode and getting a 0 on the rangeCount property in the object returned. 
I'm testing this on Chrome also and it's works correctly there, that's why I know that the values returned by Edge are not OK.

I need to know if there is a way to get the right AnchorNode and RangeCount on Edge or if there's a bug. Also, if you know a kind of workaround to make this possible please let me know.

I attached two Images where you can see the differences in the object returned by `document.getSelection()` between Chrome and Edge when the pointer focus is placed in the same element/component.

Selection object returned when calling `document.getSelection` on Chrome
[image]

Selection object returned when calling document.getSelection on Edge
[image]

------------------------- EDIT (for a more practical example) -------------------------

To give you a more practical example I tried to make a selection on the main search bar input here in StackOverflow when it was empty and it retrieved me different values between Chrome and Edge (even with text it retrieves null on Edge).

On Chrome it returned the element/component in the anchorNode and a '1' on the rangeCount but on Edge it return an object with the anchorNode null and a '0' on rangeCount.

This is the same issue I'm having on the site that I'm working on, I'm having trouble when selecting an input (which is a custom input and that's why you see a 'td' tag as an anchorNode on chrome in the previous image) and getting the rangeCount because I'm getting different values on those browsers.

PS1. I tested it using the JS console on the developer tools of each browser which is the same as using it on JS code. I also tested this getSelection function on labels and tags like p,div... as @Deepak-MSFT made it in his answer and in those tags it works fine for both browsers, the issue is when I try to use it inside a text input like the that search bar.

I'm attaching two gifs so you can see what I tested on the search bar input here in stackoverflow so you can reproduce it as well.

[Process to test document.getSelection on search bar input in Stackoverflow page on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdG4t.gif)

[Process to test document.getSelection on search bar input in Stackoverflow page on Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw2DB.gif)

------------------------- EDIT (sample code) -------------------------

Please run this code sample in both browsers, Chrome and Edge, to see their differences. Just click on the input text on type any characters

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Input text: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">

<div>Anchor Node: <b id="divsel1"></b></div>
<div>Range Count: <b id="divsel2"></b></div>

<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  var sel = document.getSelection();
  document.getElementById("divsel1").innerHTML = sel.anchorNode ? sel.anchorNode.nodeName : sel.anchorNode;
  document.getElementById("divsel2").innerHTML = sel.rangeCount;
  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). Selection API is fully supported by Edge. You sure it's not empty because  you're logging it during some click event handling immediately after selection is lost?

Comment: We need an [MCVE], with a procedure to reproduce. Your chrome's snapshot tells that you are with a collapsed Selection inside a <td> element. That's quite weird in itself, since generally focusNodes are TextNodes and rarely Elements. What are you doing to this <td>?

Comment: @Andrey I'm calling the getSelection function on the 'focus' event. I tried on different events but I keep getting the same issue. Please take a look at the question again, I edited it to add a more practical example so you can reproduce it.

Comment: @Kaiido It's a td tag because the textbox input is a custom component on my site but it works exactly as the input text. Please take a look at the question again, I edited it to add a more practical example so you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not posted any sample code so we are not sure how you are trying to get selection in your code.

I try to make a test with code below in MS Edge and looks like it is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedText () {
            if (document.getSelection) {    // all browsers, except IE before version 9
                var sel = document.getSelection ();
                    // sel is a string in Firefox and Opera, 
                    // and a selectionRange object in Google Chrome, Safari and IE from version 9
                    // the alert method displays the result of the toString method of the passed object
                alert (sel);
            } 
            else {
                if (document.selection) {   // Internet Explorer before version 9
                    var textRange = document.selection.createRange ();
                    alert (textRange.text);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Please select <b>all</b> or a <i>part</i> of this text.</div>
    <br />
    <button onclick="GetSelectedText ()">Get selected text!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge:

[image]

Reference:

[getSelection method (document)](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqxhfte.php)

If issue persist than please try to provide any sample code to produce the issue will help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: Thanks Deepak-MSFT, in this case, selecting text from a div tag, the selection works fine in both browsers. The issue is when I try to use it inside a text input like the that search bar. Please take a look at the question again, I edited it to add a more practical example so you can reproduce it.

Comment: I try to run your sample code in Chrome and Edge. Based on my testing results. I found that Chrome sometimes shows #text or body as anchor node. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/t4yb5s77/47.gif Where as Edge always shows body as anchor node with 1 range count. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/zfB9tKND/46.gif

Comment: You're right, I just realize that I was fooled by Microsoft because well, I'm on Windows 8 so I don't have Edge, but when I use IE it says Edge on the developer tools window ([look](https://postimg.cc/tYPB2rFg)) and I thought that it simulated Edge behavior but it doesn't. Now that you posted this and it worked on your environment I tested it on Edge in a Win10 OS and it worked well, so it seems that the issue here is with IE 11 which is the version of the IE browser that I'm using.

Comment: If you had got the answer for your question than I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer may help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. If you still have further questions regarding same issue than you can let us know about that. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.